# If $E=FA$ where $F$ is a nonsingular matrix, how can I show the nullspace of $A$ is the same as the nullspace of $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **E=FA** with **F** a nonsingular matrix. Show that $null(\mathbf(E)) = null(\mathbf(A))$

I know this implies that $Ax = 0$. So maybe multiplying both sides by E with give me $EAx = 0$. Since $E = FA$ and $F$ is nonsingular then $FE = FAF^{-1}$ so $FE=A$ so then $EFE = 0$. I don't even know if I'm on the right track and I'm so stuck. Can someone please help me? Thank you

Comment: @symplectomorphic Cool that you edit, but it might have been $E=FA$ instead. I would've edited myself but was waiting for explicit confirmation on which way it goes.

Comment: @Arthur: The order doesn't really matter, of course...

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes, it does. Not for the problem statement, but for how correct the calculations are. Note that he says $E=FA$ there. But also $FE=A$ and a few other things, so I can't really tell which way is supposed to be. That's why I waited.

Comment: @Arthur: Eh, fine. *Mutatis mutandis* the concept is exactly the same, since $F$ is nonsingular.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That's not really better. Again, if it had been clear from the calculations which way it goes, _I would've edited myself_. The calculations, however, seem somewhat confused, so it's difficult to tell whether it's $A=FE$ or $E=FA$ which is actually meant. Be careful when editing ambiguous stuff, especially when, like here, it matters for the rest of the post.

Comment: @Arthur: I agree with you it's ambiguous. That's why I deleted my answer and am waiting, myself: I didn't read the OP's calculations initially because they're obviously terribly confused. Yes, the OP's calculations are based on it being one way or the other, but it is *also* instructive for the OP to hear that it doesn't actually matter whether it's $E=FA$ or $A=FE$, because the one problem is turned into the other by multiplying by $F^{-1}$. If an exhortation to "be careful" is in order, it should be issued to the OP, not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the null space of A is a subset of the null space of E. Now let v be in the null space of E. It follows that because F is invertible, it has a trivial kernel and hence A must send v to zero. Since v is arbitrary, the null space of E is a subset of the null space of A, and hence the two subspaces are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The following are equivalent (why?):

1. $x\in \mathrm{null}(A)$
2. $Ax = 0$
3. $FAx = F0$